# Meteor.JS - "remember me" into customized login form

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm trying to perform a customized login form with Meteor (I think it's the easiest solution when you use Meteor with Angular, Bootstrap...).

Everything is functionnal but **I would like users still connected** ("Remember me" checkbox).

I can't find any information about this thing into the Meteor documentation, Meteor API or World Wide Web.

Any idea for doing this functionnality ?

Thanks !
Aurélien :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remembering the user is the default meteor behaviour on login. If you want more customisation check this https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-accounts-remember-me-option/26295